# How to use [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer with credential from Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

Which kind of credentials must I provide, to get this working

```
$tfsServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($basePath,$credential)
```

I tried:

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($user,$password)
```

and

```
$credential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $password, $domane)
```

and always got

```
Für "GetServer" und die folgende Argumenteanzahl kann keine Überladung gefunden werden: "2".
Bei Zeile:18 Zeichen:86
+ $tfsServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer <<<< ($basePath,$credential)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I want to use

```
TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer Method (String, ICredentialsProvider)
```

cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb136201%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The background is, that I want to call this in a remote PowerShell session and for some reason, I do not understand

```
$tfsServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($basePath)
```

yields

"TF30063: You are not authorized to access mytfs\MccCollection."

Comment: TFS 2008 or another versión?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"

$Assem = ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$Source =  @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.Net;
public class ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider
    {
        public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials iCredentials)
        {
            return new NetworkCredential("myuser", "myPassword", "mydomain");
        }

        public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to authenticate");
        }
    }
"@

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

$basePath = "http://mytfs:8080/tfs/MyCollection"
$tfsServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($basePath, (New-Object ConnectByImplementingCredentialsProvider) )
$tfsServer.EnsureAuthenticated()
```

When executed for the first time, `$tfsServer.EnsureAuthenticated()` throws an error, but afterwards it is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

The `TeamFoundationServerFactory` expects a `ICredentialsProvider` implementation as @Berns_k shows in his answer. If you already have the credentials you should use a different way of instantiating your `TfsTeamProjectCollection`:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://yourserver:8080/tfs/Collection"),
    new NetworkCredential("myuser", "myPassword", "mydomain");
);
```

or in powershell:

```
$cred = New-Object NetworkCredential("myuser", "myPassword", "mydomain")
$tpc = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection
(
     $basePath,
     $cred
)
```

That way you don't need to create a Credential Provider and you should not get any error on your first call to `EnsureAuthenticated`.

Answer (score -1):

you are calling the new-object incorrectly to create the credential

```
$Username = "domain\username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘MySekurePassw0rd42!’ -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username,$Password
```