# Why does TFS Authentification fail from remote PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-remoting

When I run the following PowerShell script directly on a machine

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"

$basePath = "http://magv-dev-tfs:8080/tfs/MccCollection"
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($basePath)
```

I get an objects, with the fields AuthenticatedUserName, AuthenticatedUserDisplayName, AuthenticatedUserIdentity set.

When I run the same script in a remote PowerShellTab from some other machine on the same machine using the sam e credentials, then these 3 fields are emply:

```
AuthenticatedUserName           : 
AuthenticatedUserDisplayName    : 
AuthenticatedUserIdentity       : 
Uri                             : http://my-tfs:8080/tfs/mcccollection
TimeZone                        : System.CurrentSystemTimeZone
InstanceId                      : 
Name                            : my-tfs\MccCollection
Credentials                     : System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential
Culture                         : de-DE
SessionId                       : 7c76a150-f681-4b3c-9b0d-2836a3a5a908
ClientCacheDirectoryForInstance : 
HasAuthenticated                : False
TfsTeamProjectCollection        : magv-dev-tfs\MccCollection
```

Edit:

At least I found a work around [How to use [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer with credential from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864682/how-to-use-microsoft-teamfoundation-client-teamfoundationserverfactorygetser/11877883#11877883)

Comment: I just bumped into exactly this issue; I'm hoping to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add a -credential argument to the invoke-command call?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Visual Studio TFS, PowerShell can access the connections that you have registered when you connected to your project.  [RegisteredTfsConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.registeredtfsconnections.aspx) provides access to the registered connections, so you don't have to bother with putting your credentials into the code.

The following snippet connects to a TFS server, and returns a WorkItem.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")
$regProjCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.RegisteredTfsConnections]::GetProjectCollection("tfs2010\TFS2010-MyCollection")
$tfsTeamProjCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($regProjCollection)
$ws = $tfsTeamProjCollection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")
$ws.GetWorkItem(2525)
```